# Is there a way to pass data to other components in react-native-router-flux(Without access to Actions)

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I know that I can do something like this:

```
Actions.routeName(someDataObject)
```

What if I want to add an initial props to a a component rendered by a scene at creation?
At this point 'Actions' is unavailable?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Just realized that any props passed to the 'Scene' component are available in the component that is being rendered by that scene.

So, something like this

```
           <Scene
              key={route.key}
              component={route.component}
              initialProps={route.initialProps}
              title={route.title}
              hideNavBar={route.hideNavBar}
              hideDrawerButton={false}
              initial={route.initial}
            />
```

will mean that initialProps will be available in 'props.component'.

Comment: I guess what i really wanted is to pass data as props to a component, In a way that the data is lost upon navigation to another scene.